# Multiple jQuery deferred objects in a when

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

So, if I have multiple Ajax calls, is it possible for each of them to have `done` callback and be in a `when` `then?`?

Comment: I guess you got to make an individual deferred object for each http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course it's possible. The `done` method even returns the promise, so you can simply write

```
$.when(
    $.ajax(…).done(function(r) {
        console.log("ajax 1 resolved with", r)
    }),
    $.ajax(…).done(function(r) {
        console.log("ajax 2 resolved with", r)
    })
).done(function(r1s, r2s) {
    console.log("both ajax requests done");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Promises and deferred objects take a bit to wrap my mind around. Your answer helped a ton

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to set each ajax call as a deferred object and then set the deferred objects to resolved in the .then() method.

Comment: What do you mean by "*set as a deferred object*"? Maybe post a short code example.